# How do I import from any block html element into google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=IMPORTHTML("https://theorderhound.net/leaningtower/","p",13)

I am trying to dynamically import specific items from a non-list or non-table html block element into google sheets. This is what I tried with no success, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue analysis

`IMPORTHTML` Imports data from a **table** or **list** within an HTML page.

You **cannot** use this function to import anything that is not an HTML table or list element.

To import generic HTML or other type of structured markup language elements you should therefore use the `IMPORTXML` function. It imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

### How to use IMPORTXML

`IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query)`

- **url** - The URL of the page to examine, including protocol (e.g. http://).
  The value for url must either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing the appropriate text.
- **xpath_query** - The XPath query to run on the structured data.

For more information on XPath, see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp.

To import `p` elements in particular you should change your formula to this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://theorderhound.net/leaningtower/","//p")
```

### References

[IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en)

[IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

[XPATH](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)